# "Flask run" and "python3 app.py" run on different ports

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, cors

I have a flask project. I am running app.run(port=8000, debug=True). The port was originally port 5000, and now it is port 8000. It only runs from port 8000 when I run "python3 app.py" and it runs from the old port when I run "flask run."

I was also getting some CORS error with flask run when connecting my client/server code.

My .env file has these contents:
export FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_APP=app.py

If anyone is able to shed light on this issue that would be fantastic, thanks so much!

app.py:

```
`
from flask import Flask, jsonify 
from flask_cors import CORS 
import os 
from controllers.display import display_bp
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__) # update application instantly 
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}}, supports_credentials=True)

@app.route('/shark', methods=['GET'])
def shark():
      return "message!"

app.register_blueprint(display_bp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
      app.run(port=8000, debug=True)
```

`

Comment: need more info, share your app.py file

Comment: _My .env file has these contents_ I don't think flask supports `.env` files by default.  You have to install the `python-dotenv` module for that.

Comment: I did run the command "pip3 install python-dotenv" and its still having the same issue sadly!

Answer (score 1):

Like Dave said, when you use the flask cli command to run your project it doesn't execute the `app.run()` part of your code, the flask cli will do it and it will do it with its own defaults.

You can add to your `.env` file the line `FLASK_RUN_PORT=8000` so it run on port 8000. You can read more about setting command options in [flasks cli documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/cli/#setting-command-options)

> Click is configured to load default values for command options from environment variables. The variables use the pattern FLASK_COMMAND_OPTION

Answer (score 0):

When you use `flask run`,

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

evaluates to `False`, and

```
app.run(port=8000, debug=True)
```

isn't executed.

Comment: What is executed?

Comment: Oh weird! Do you know how to change the port with flask run?

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/cli/#setting-command-options